# How to Default a Form Field Value from a Table Field Value? (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, default-value

How to Default a Form Field Value from a Table Field Value?

I have a `[Table].[Field]` called `[Local_Role_Filter].[Role]`. It will only ever have 1 record.

How do I use the value within `[Local_Role_Filter].[Role]` as the Default of a Form Field Value?

I've been searching all day long, but I'm still stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Default Value` field of property box of textbox use

```
=DLOOKUP("[Role]","[Local_Role_Filter]")
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a gem! Thank you so much @Harun24HR